# Spaces $ T_ {0} $ and their equivalences

Tags: general-topology

X is $T_{0}$ if, and only if,  given $ x, y\in X $, with $ x \neq y$, there is a neighborhood of one of them that does not contain the other.

$y\in A^{d}$ if, and only if, $y\in\overline{{A\setminus{\{y\}}}}$

Let $ X $ be a topological space. They are equivalent:

I). $ X $ is $ T_ {0} $;

II). $ \overline {\{x \}} \neq \overline {\{y\}} $, for each $ x \neq y$, $ x, y\in X $;

III). If $ x \in \{y\} ^ {d} $, then $ y\notin \{x \} ^ {d} $, for each $ x \neq y$, $ x, y\in X $;

IV). $ \{x \} ^ {d} $ is the union of closed sets, for each $ x \in X $.

I was able to show $ I) \rightarrow {II)} $, $ II) \rightarrow {III)} $, but I was not able to show $ III) \rightarrow {IV)} $ and $ IV) \rightarrow {I)} $. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define  $T_0$ space? Is it the space in which every point set is closed or something else?

Comment: @ThomasShelby I just added the definition

Comment: {x}$^d$????????

Comment: @WilliamElliot I just added the definition

Comment: A smoother statement of II is:  for all x,y, ($ \overline {\{x \}} = \overline {\{y\}} $ iff x = y).

Comment: @WilliamElliot $d$ is for *derived set*.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\{x\}'$ is also a common notation, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Why go cyclic? III) implies I) is easier, maybe. So let $x \neq y$. Suppose first that $x \in \{y\}^d$. Then III tells us that $y \notin \{x\}^d$ which means that there is an open set $V$ containing $y$ such that $x \notin V$, and we are done. So the other case is that $x \notin \{y\}^d$ so there is an open set containing $x$ such that $y \notin U$ and again we have shown the $T_0$ property for $x$ and $y$.

The reverse I implies III is very similar: suppose $x \neq y$ and $x \in \{y\}^d$. Then either we have some open $U$ that that contains $x$ but not $y$ or some open $V$ that contains $y$ but not $x$. But $x$ being in $\{y\}^d$  means that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains $y$, so the first cannot be the case. So we have such a $V$, which then witnesses that $y \notin \{x\}^d$.

Note that for $x \neq y$, $x \in \{y\}^d$ iff $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$.

Now the first III have been shown equivalent so you can show IV implies I or II or III and one of I /II/III implies IV to complete the equivalence proof.

To give an idea for IV: if $x \in X$, then show that

$$\{x\}^d = \bigcup \{\overline{\{y\}}: y \in \{x\}^d\}$$

when $X$ obeys II) or III) (or just I)).

And if $x \neq y$, write $\{x\}^d = \overline{\{x\}}\setminus \{x\} = \bigcup_i F_i$, a union of closed sets. If $y \notin \{x\}^d$, this means it has an open neighbourhood missing $x$ and we're done showing I), and otherwise, $y \in F_i$ for some $i$, but then clearly $X\setminus F_i$ is open does not contain $y$ but does contain $x$ and we again have that I) holds.

Comment: If $x\neq y$, write $\{x\}^{d}=\overline{\{x\}}\setminus{\{x\}}=\bigcup_{i}{F_{i}}$, right? Why is that true?

Comment: That's trivially true, since $ \overline {\{x \}} = \{x \} \cup {\{x \} ^ {d}} $, right? But I'm not sure if $ \overline {\{x \}}\setminus{\{x\}} = \bigcup_ {i} {F_ {i}} $

Comment: This $ \{x \} ^ d = \bigcup \{\overline {\{y\}}: y\in \{x \} ^ d \} $ confuses me. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Darkmaster the assumption of IV) is that the derived set of a singleton is a union of closed sets.

Comment: @Darkmaster yes, try to show that identity from III), say.

Comment: I have a doubt. We know that III) is valid for every $ x, y \in X $, with $ x \neq y$. I want to prove that identity. let $ z \in \{x \} ^ {d} $ be. Then two things can happen. The first is that $ z = x $ and the second is that $ z \neq x $. In the second, I can use the hypothesis, it is valid for all the pairs of different points, but in the first case I do not know what to do or I am misunderstanding the statement III).

Comment: @Darkmaster $z=x$ cannot happen as $x \notin \{x\}^d$ for all $x$!

Comment: Otherwise, $ z \in \overline {\emptyset} = \emptyset $, which is absurd, right?
As $ z \in \{x \} ^ {d} \Longleftrightarrow z \in \overline {\{x \}} $, since $ z \neq x $ right? Then $z\in \overline {\{x \}}\subseteq\bigcup{\{\overline{\{y\}}|y\in\{x\}^{d}\}}$, right?

Comment: @Darkmaster Yes, that's about right. The other inclusion is trivial.

Comment: Is that trivial inclusion? Really?

Comment: @Darkmaster If $y \in \{x\}^d$ then $x \notin \{y\}^d$ by III), and $\overline{\{y\}} \subseteq \overline{\{x\}}\setminus \{x\} = \{x\}^d$ for the other inclusion.

Comment: I have a doubt. This identity does not contradict II)? I ask you because you say, more or less, that $ \overline {\{x \}} = \overline {\{y \}} $, right?

Comment: @Darkmaster No, it doesn't, it says it's possibly a union of smaller closures of singletons, that are all distinct from the closure of $x$.